# Allowing to pass variables without telling data types?

Tags: c

I have this following code that executes successfully but how is it possible when function `printit` is not having data types of passed variables. And then why in output float value is printed correctly but character value is not. I tried even by typecasting it to `char`.

```
main( )
{
    float a = 15.5 ;
    char ch = 'C' ;
    printit ( a, ch ) ;
}

printit ( a, ch )
{
    printf ( "\n%f %c", a, ch ) ;
}
```

Its execution gives the result:

```
15.500000 ╠
```

Comment: You're using the default int behaviour of K&R C and lying to the compiler, so all you can expect is undefined behaviour.

Comment: What C compiler do you use ?

Comment: `g++` as default in codeblocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pre-standard C, that was a permitted, though even then not encouraged, way of writing code.  There were no prototypes; in the absence of a type specifier, variables were of type `int`.

If the types were not `int`, you might write:

```
print_it_2(a, b, c)
    struct dohickey *c;
    double b;
{
    printf("%d %p %f\n", a, b, c);
}
```

Note that the variables are listed in one order and defined in another, and `a` is still an `int` because it isn't listed at all.  The return type of the function was assumed to be `int` too.  However, especially if the function didn't return a value after all (this was before the return type `void` was supported), people would omit the return type from the declaration and not return a value from the function.

This is no longer good style.  If the compiler doesn't complain about it, it should.  I compile code (especially for answers on SO) with the extra options:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
        -Wold-style-definition -Werror ll3.c -o ll3
```

The missing prototypes and strict prototypes and old style definition are about expunging the last vestiges of such old, pre-standard code.  I don't always (usually) show those three options in my answers, but they're there when I compile the code.  It means you'll see functions made `static` (to avoid missing prototypes) and `int main(void)` instead of `int main()` (to avoid strict prototypes), and old style definition would shout about the functions discussed in the question.

---

The second part of the question is 'why did the float value get printed correctly and the character not'.

One of the ways in which non-prototype functions vary is that automatic promotions apply.  Any type smaller than `int` (so `char` or `short`) is promoted to `int`, and `float` is promoted to `double` (simplifying slightly).  So, in the call `printit(a, ch)`, the values actually passed are a `double` and an `int`.  Inside the function, the code thinks that `a` is an `int` (for concreteness, a 4 byte `int`), and ditto for `ch`.  These two 4 byte quantities are copied onto the stack (again, simplifying slightly), and passed to `printf()`.  Now, `printf()` is a variadic function (takes a variable number of arguments), and the arguments passed as part of the ellipsis `...` are automatically promoted too.  So inside `printf()`, it is told there are 8 bytes on the stack containing a `double` value, and sure enough, the calling code passed 8 bytes (albeit as two 4-byte units), so the `double` is magically preserved.  Then `printf()` is told that there's an extra `int` on the stack, but the `int` was not put there by the calling code, so it reads some other indeterminate value and prints that character.

This sort of mess is what prototypes prevent.  That's why you should never code in this style any more (and that has been true for all of this millennium and even for the latter half of the last decade of the previous millennium).

---

[Peter Schneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150802/peter-schneider) asks in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761079/c-allowing-to-pass-variables-without-telling-data-types/22761327?noredirect=1#comment34698122_22761327):

> Can you point to the relevant standard which allows or forbids undeclared parameters? If it is indeed forbidden, why does `gcc` not conform to the standard when asked to?

Taking that code and compiling with GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2, I get:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -c xyz.c
xyz.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]
 print_it_2(a, b, c)
 ^
xyz.c: In function ‘print_it_2’:
xyz.c:1:1: warning: type of ‘a’ defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]
xyz.c:5:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%d %p %f\n", a, b, c);
     ^
xyz.c:5:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
$
```

The same warnings are given with `-std=c99`.  However:

```
$ gcc -std=c89 -c xyz.c
xyz.c: In function ‘print_it_2’:
xyz.c:5:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
     printf("%d %p %f\n", a, b, c);
     ^
$
```

And by providing `#include <stdio.h>`, even that would be quelled.

Section 6.9.1 of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 covers function definitions (and it's the same section number in C99).  However, both of these rule out the 'implicit `int`' behaviour that C89 had to permit (because an awful lot of pre-existing code hadn't heard of the rules.

However, even C11 allows for the old style definition (with complete types):

> *function-definition:
>
>       declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-list<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement*
>
> *declaration-list:
>
>       declaration
>
>       declaration-list declaration*

The 'declaration-list<sub>opt</sub>' is the list of types between the function declarator and the compound statement that is the function body.

C11 also says:

> §6 If the declarator includes an identifier list, each declaration in the declaration list shall
>   have at least one declarator, those declarators shall declare only identifiers from the
>   identifier list, and every identifier in the identifier list shall be declared.

I can't immediately find my copy of 'The Annotated C Standard', a book which contains useful information (the 1989/1990 C standard) on the left hand page and frequently less-than-useful information on the right hand page of each spread.  This would allow me to quote the standard, but it is AWOL at the moment.

C89 would have been less stringently worded in this paragraph §6.

As to why `gcc` doesn't reject the sloppily written old-style code, the answer is still 'backwards compatibility'.  There is still old code out there, and it allows it to compile when it can, unless its hands are carefully tied behind its back by the use of `-Werror`.

Comment: But to my amazement, gcc compiles this even with -std=c11. Of course you can always consider warnings as errors but that is often not possible with third party code. Can you point to the relevant standard which allows or forbids undeclared parameters? If it is indeed forbidden, why does gcc not conform to the standard when asked to?